# Does anyone know how to connect 2 digipots to Arduino? (MCP4141)

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

I'm struggling with getting the code right. I'm trying to connect 2 digipots (MCP 4141) to Arduino to work separately over SPI. Has anyone got any experience with that?

Comment: Do you have one working?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you trying to achieve? Can you provide links to the supplier of the digipots? Do they have any example code? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read the datasheet and get a basic understanding of how the device works. in this case, it consists of 16 bits transfer (2 bytes).

Try to write a set of routines that communicates with the chip over the spi.

After that, it is all about using the _CS pin to select a particular chip.

edit: if this helps you, here is my code driving two mcp41010 - slight different from your digit pot but very similar.

```
//write to the device wiper0
void mcp41xxx_write0(uint8_t dat) {
    spi_write(MCP41XXX_P0 | MCP41XXX_CMD_WRITE);    //send the command byte
    spi_write(dat);                                 //send the data byte
}

//write to the device wiper1
void mcp41xxx_write1(uint8_t dat) {
    spi_write(MCP41XXX_P1 | MCP41XXX_CMD_WRITE);    //send the command byte
    spi_write(dat);                                 //send the data byte
}
```

the actual writes to the devices will differ -> mine is specific to the mcp41010 devices. It supports two wipers, P0 and P1. No increment or decrement on my digit pots.

the way to drive two digit pots are below:

```
//first pot
spi_select(MCP41XXX_CS1);           //deselect cs1 -> idles high
mcp41xxx_write0(i + i);             //send the data
spi_deselect(MCP41XXX_CS1);         //select hte device

//second pot
spi_select(MCP41XXX_CS2);           //deselect cs1 -> idles high
mcp41xxx_write0(i++);               //send the data
spi_deselect(MCP41XXX_CS2);         //select the device
```

as i'm using a single pot device, writing to the 2nd pot means writing to its wiper0.

[image]

I looked at your digit pot and the only thing you need to change are the wiper-specific routine(s), as your transmission is slightly different in the msb.

the spi_write() routine can be replaced / mapped to the shiftOut() routine under arduino.

here is the above code, without any change, running on an arduino:

[image]

I also took a brief look at your device's datasheet (mcp4141) and I think this is all you need to change:

```
//send data on wiper0 of mcp4141
void mcp41xx_write0(uint16_t dat) {
    dat = dat & 0x03ff;                             //10-bit data
    spi_write(MCP41XX_CMD_WRITE | MCP41XX_WIPER0 | (dat >>  8));    //write the msb
    spi_write(dat);                                 //write the lsb
}
```